# Making a DB call from EDT thread

Tags: java, swing

In a JPanel, I have combobox in order to update the combobox with details. I need to query from backend Database. This makes the entire GUI freeze.

```
if (ccyPairs.size() == 0) {
  try {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PropertyFile.getInstance().getSmfTable() + " WHERE SECURITYTYPE = 4 ";
    Security[] securities = SecurityMaster.getInstance().getData(query, false);
    for (Security security : securities) {
      String Symbol = security.getSymbol();
      ccyPairs.add(Symbol);
    }
  } catch (Exception exception) {
    Log.error(getClass().getName(), "getValidSymbols", "Exception occurred while retrieving fx symbols from smf table " + exception.getMessage());
  }

  return ccyPairs;
}
return ccyPairs;
```

Here 
  Security[] securities = SecurityMaster.getInstance().getData(query, false); is a call to database.

Can anyone please explain how to solve this problem?

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to understand what the problem is and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I use worker.get() does it blocks EDT?

Comment: Yes, it will block until the worker's `doInBackground` method returns or throws an `Exception`

Comment: @MadProgrammer But my aim is not to block EDT untill I do DB call

Comment: Then use the works done method to call get (if you want the result) and call some callback to let, who ever is interested, that the worker has completed

Answer (score 1):

You should use a SwingWorker as explained in [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to free up your EDT while the DB fetches data.